# ASP.NET session drop event

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, session-variables

Is theire a way, to get noticed if an asp.net web forms session is droped (For example, the client cloeses the browser = timeout)?

We have one session for the temporary user shopping card:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserShoppingCard"] = new UserShoppingCard();
```

Every thing works fine, besides the functions explanied above.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe there is any communication with the server until a request is made. I do this with jQuery and AJAX. I request an ASP.Net web service every 30 seconds to act as a keep-alive service. Something like this would probably be your best bet.

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates Thank you for your answer. I don't get what you mean. It is no problem that the session is droped, i only need this information for sending an E-Mail.

Comment: @BendEg you make absolutely no sense. think about it, you are trying to store the new object in your **SESSION**, if the session is dropped, where are you trying to save it exactly?

Comment: I don't want to save anything, @Dave Piras answer seems to be correct, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to intercept the **Session_End** event in the global.asax file and put some logging in there, it might not happen right when the browser is closed but it will happen at some point anyway once the session is terminated and you can include your logic in there.

In fact the server never knows when a browser is closed or if instead a connection issue is making the client unable to connect.

Comment: I think, every session stores the last access time, and after the timeout is reached, the seesion will be expired.

Comment: @BendEg Yeah, the last paragraph threw me off :) The one before it explains it - _"...some point anyway..."_

Answer (score 3):

As said before, complementing with code...

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your things here when session ends...
    }
}
```